# NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol is not being recognized as a static property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, globalization

I'm writing a WPF application in which i want to display the currency symbol of the selected culture on the form.

So i have added this text block

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static globalization:NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol}" Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

The compiler is complaining that it cannot find **NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo** although this is a static property in a public class.
In the same form i'm able to successfully refer to *CultureInfo.CurrentCulture* from the same namespace. This confirms that i have nothing wrong in my namespace declaration.

My workaround is to provide an x:Name to the textblock and then assign its text from the code behind, but i want to do it the right way.

Thanks,
Fadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message carefully, it says where the problem is:

> Cannot find the **type** 'NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo'.

It's looking for the property `CurrencySymbol` of the *type* `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`, which doesn't exist. To bind to that property, you can use the `CurrentInfo` as a source for `Binding`:

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static globalization:NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo}, Path=CurrencySymbol}"
```

Comment: Thank you. Lesson Learned, the format for x:Static is fixed
"namespace:Class.Property"